# Buttons in a horizontal panel don't want to align right

Tags: java, gwt

I have a horizontal panel with 3 buttons: Back, Next and Cancel. I've made horizontal alignment to the right, but only Next and Cancel buttons follow this alignment.

Here is the code:

```
HorizontalPanel buttons = new HorizontalPanel();
buttons.setWidth("100%");

cancel = new Button("Cancel");
next = new Button("Next");
back = new Button("Back");

buttons.setHorizontalAlignment(HasHorizontalAlignment.ALIGN_RIGHT);
buttons.add(back);
buttons.setCellWidth(back, "98%");
buttons.add(nextBtn);
buttons.setCellWidth(next, "1%");
buttons.add(cancel);
buttons.setCellWidth(cancel, "1%");
```

The problem is with this panel width. But if I delete it, all my buttons are left aligned. As a workaround I can use false button, that will be invisible and has cell width = 97%, the cell width of back button is 1%. But this is not what I need, because inspite of small amount of memory this invisible button consumes, it is still a memory :)

What is going wrong with this alignment? Maybe something is wrong with panel width? Hope for your help, thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this much easier using css:

```
FlowPanel panel = new FlowPanel();
panel.setWidth("100%");

cancel = new Button("Cancel");
cancel.getElement().getStyle().setFloat(Float.RIGHT);
next = new Button("Next");
next.getElement().getStyle().setFloat(Float.RIGHT);
back = new Button("Back");
back.getElement().getStyle().setFloat(Float.RIGHT);

panel.add(back);
panel.add(nextBtn);
panel.add(cancel);
```

Comment: Thank you, this one helped me.

Answer (score 3):

There is **setCellHorizontalAlignment()** property in **HorizontalPanel**. With it you can give alignment to its widgets.

Try following:

```
buttons.setCellHorizontalAlignment(backButton, HasHorizontalAlignment.ALIGN_RIGHT);
buttons.setCellHorizontalAlignment(nextButton, HasHorizontalAlignment.ALIGN_RIGHT);
buttons.setCellHorizontalAlignment(cancelButton, HasHorizontalAlignment.ALIGN_RIGHT);
```

Comment: Good solution, but "Back" button is still left-aligned :(